# How to customize the ticks of hexbin?

Tags: r, graphics

https://r-graph-gallery.com/100-high-density-scatterplot-with-binning.html

```
library(hexbin)
library(RColorBrewer)
 
# Create data
x <- rnorm(mean=1.5, 5000)
y <- rnorm(mean=1.6, 5000)
 
# Make the plot
bin<-hexbin(x, y, xbins=40)
my_colors=colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral')))
plot(bin, main="" , colramp=my_colors , legend=F )
```

In the above example, I don't see a way to customize the ticks. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Turn off the axes in the plot command with `xaxt="n"` and/or `yaxt="n"`. Then use the `axis()` function to customize the axes. Other ways to alter the axes are documented in `?par`.

Comment: Did you try it? axis() won't work. hexbin uses grid instead of base R graphics.